# How to add images to resource chooser?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm bulding app for the first time for android in eclipse. I have my own images which I have added to assets folder.

I want to put ImageView over UI but there isn't any of my images in resource chooser.
[image]

How to add images to appear in resource chooser?

Comment: Just move these images under /res/drawable folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your image at res/drawable-hdpi.

Than you can see your image on resource chooser.

- Sorry to some broken english :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your images in res/drawable folder by convention. 
 
In res folder there could be more than one drawable folder like res/drawable-ldpi, res/drawable-mdpi, res/drawable-hdpi, res/drawable-xhdpi, and res/drawable-tvdpi. 
 
You might be creating an app for different phones with different screen resolutions and screen sizes. 
 
Android have a categorization of phone screens according to the dpi of the screen, namely ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, tvdpi (low, med, high, xtra high, tv respectively).
 
Your goal is to add each copy of images to these folders for each type of your target devices. 
For that you have to resize your images in the dpi ratio.

3:4:6:8 is the default dpi scaling ratio

Refresh your workspace and call the images by `"@drawable/name_of_image"` through **xml** or `setImageResource(R.drawable.name_of_image)` through **java**. 
Important thing is to omit extension of the image when referencing. Like **name_of_image.png** is called as `@drawable/name_of_image`

Comment: Thanks for your answers, it is more clear now but something is still confusing. Opened another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923687/how-sort-images-by-resolution-and-density

Comment: what ever the screen size and resolution, same images apply for similar dpi screens. Android will automatically resize your images to fit in the screen as you defined regardless of the size and resolution but on basis of dpi.