# How sort images by resolution and density?

Tags: android, eclipse

On this page in table 3 at the bottom it says there are small, normal, large and extra large screen for each density (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi): http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support

For example, if I create mdpi normal screen (320x480) and mdpi large screen (600x1024) should I put all images for both resolutions in mdpi folder? If yes, how should I name those images because those are the same images with different sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
should I put all images for both resolutions in mdpi folder?
```

Yes. The size of the images should be the same among all screen sizes, they should vary only by density.

In this case you should use `drawable-mdpi` and treat your layout to better use the extra space you may have in larger screens.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to give images specifically for large screen mdpi then you can create a new folder drawable-large-mdpi.

Check out : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers

Answer (score 1):

What ever the screen size and resolution, same images apply for similar dpi screens.
 
Android will automatically resize your images to fit in the screen as you defined regardless of the size and resolution but on basis of dpi.

That means you have to put same images for all same dpi layouts.

Answer (score 0):

From the same [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html):

**To use a configuration qualifier:**

*Create a new directory in your project's res/ directory and name it using the format: -
 is the standard resource name (such as drawable or layout).
 is a configuration qualifier from table 1, below, specifying the screen configuration for which these resources are to be used (such as hdpi or xlarge).
You can use more than one  at a time—simply separate each qualifier with a dash.
Save the appropriate configuration-specific resources in this new directory. The resource files must be named exactly the same as the default resource files.*

Search for "Using configuration qualifiers"